# Use <p:ajax event="onRowSelect"> to update a button

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using `<p:ajax event="onRowSelect" update="editButton deleteButton">` to switch `disabled` attribute in `<p:commandButton>`, but it's not working properly.

Here is my code:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="editButton deleteButton"/>
...
<p:commandButton id="editButton" icon="ui-icon-pencil" value="#{appBundle.Edit}" action="detail.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" disabled="#{empty academicManagedBean.academicSelected}">
```

Did I do anything wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is my managed bean class:

```
package com.rdb.beans;

import com.rdb.entities.TblAcademic;
import com.rdb.entities.TblClass;
import com.rdb.entities.TblStudent;
import com.rdb.util.JsfUtil;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

/**
 *
 * @author NNToan
 */
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AcademicManagedBean extends TblAcademic implements Serializable {

    private List<TblAcademic> all;
    private static TblAcademic academicSelected;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of AcademicManagedBean
     *
     */
    public AcademicManagedBean() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Get all records in TblAcademic from the database.
     *
     * @return List<TblAcademic>
     */
    public List<TblAcademic> getAll() {
        try {
            all = new com.rdb.bll.AcademicBLL().getAll();
            return all;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BranchManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add new record to the database Show action status at growl
     *
     * @param actionEvent
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void add(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        boolean check = new com.rdb.bll.AcademicBLL().add(this);
        if (check) {
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Congratulation, new student has been added successfully!");
        } else {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.rdb.service.AppBundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update student information Show action status at growl
     *
     * @param actionEvent
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void update(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        boolean check = new com.rdb.bll.AcademicBLL().update(AcademicManagedBean.academicSelected);
        if (check) {
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Congratulation, student has been updated successfully!");
        } else {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.rdb.service.AppBundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete student from the database Show action status at growl
     *
     * @param actionEvent
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void delete(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        boolean check = new com.rdb.bll.AcademicBLL().delete(AcademicManagedBean.academicSelected);
        if (check) {
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Congratulation, student has been deleted successfully!");
        } else {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.rdb.service.AppBundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Enter student edit-mode
     *
     * @return detail.xhtml?faces-redirect=true
     */
    public String studentDetail() {
        TblStudent std = new com.rdb.bll.StudentBLL().getById(AcademicManagedBean.academicSelected.getStudentRollNo());
        new StudentManagedBean().setStudentSelected(std);

        return "detail.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    /**
     * Get class name through class identifier
     *
     * @param classId
     * @return className
     */
    public String getClassNameById(int classId) {
        TblClass objClass = new com.rdb.bll.ClassBLL().getById(classId);
        return objClass.getClassName();
    }

    /**
     * Get current working object (selected row)
     *
     * @return TblAcademic
     */
    public TblAcademic getAcademicSelected() {
        return academicSelected;
    }

    /**
     * Set current working object (selected row)
     *
     * @param academicSelected
     */
    public void setAcademicSelected(TblAcademic academicSelected) {
        AcademicManagedBean.academicSelected = academicSelected;
    }
}
```

Comment: How this condition #{empty academicManagedBean.academicSelected} is supposed to change on row selection? You need maybe to show more code or clarify this point.

Comment: you should add a listener method where you switch the property academicSelected wrt your desired condition.

Comment: How is it not working properly? Are you getting an error?  Is it not behaving how it should?

Comment: I edited in my question.
@elbuild: Here is the image link which I described what I want how the event work. [link](https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4jzxb/kxj2?size=o)